# SharePoint2013 development with VS2012 express

Tags: development

Is it possible to develop SharePoint 2013 related things using Visual Studio 2012 express?

Answer (score 6):

Prashant,

The developer tools for SharePoint 2013 are not included in VS and you need to install the tools, the url is here:
[Download the tools, products, and resources you need to create apps for Office and SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps/fp123627)

If you see on these tools, its written that:
**The tools require Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Premium, or Professional.**

Which answers your question! No Express cannot be used for SharePoint 2013 development